# How to randomize Strings?

Tags: android

***How can I randomize Strings?*** I have *3 Strings*, and *1 TextView*. To the TextViev, I Would like to "write" the string, when **a button is clicked**.
My code is:

***main xml:***

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
    android:text="Push Me"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
    tools:ignore="UnknownId" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="VALAMI"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="182dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:ignore="UnknownId" />
```

***MainActivity.java***

```
Button btn1;
TextView tv1;

String a = "s1";
String b = "s2";
String c = "s3";
```

Comment: `I don't have any code` ... then you might not be ready to ask a question on Stack Overflow.  Off the top of my head, what you want to do seems easy, but without code I can't give an exact answer.

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ArrayList<String> strings = {"s1", "s2", "s3"};


    Button button = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    TextView text = findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick(View v){

       Random randomno = new Random();
       text.setText(strings.get(randomno.nextInt(3));


       } 

    });
}
```

Comment: I have problems with it:  Error:(20, 33) error: illegal initializer for ArrayList<String>
Error:(35, 33) error: cannot find symbol variable randomGenerator
In this line: int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);    , the randomGenerator is looking red,and the code is not runnung.

Comment: @TamasKatona create object of random class  ...........  Random randomno = new Random();
       text.setText(strings.get(randomno.nextInt(3));

Comment: and how can I do that?

Comment: How can I add an object of random class?

Comment: There is the class Random https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html